# Convergence in a metric spaces and infinite sequences

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $Y \subset M$. Prove that, if $y \in \overline {Y}$, exists a sequence $(y_n)$ with $y_n \in Y$ for all $n$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$. Prove that, if $y_n \in Y'$, the sequence is infinite.

How can we use the definition:

If $y \in \overline {Y}$, for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $B(y;\epsilon)\cap Y \ne \emptyset$.

To solve this? I don't know how i can get a sequence from this. I do think that the infinite sequence will be "easy" to solve, cause i'm the list of exercises where this question is, we have a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $B(y, \frac{1}{n})\cap Y$ is nonempty so we can choose some $y_n\in B(y, \frac{1}{n})\cap Y$.

Now show that $y_n\to y$